# Is the following thread-safe? 4 threads writing to same data structure

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, thread-safety

So let's say I have 4 threads and they all loop through an array with 100 indices, flipping the bits of the info in each index and writing back to that index...

```
arr[];

Thread 1:

for (int i = 0; i< 100; i+=4) { flip bits of arr[i]}

Thread 2:

for (int j = 1; j< 100; j+=4) { flip bits of arr[j]}

Thread 3:

for (int k = 2; k< 100; k+=4) { flip bits of arr[k]}

Thread 4:

for (int l = 3; l< 100; l+=4) { flip bits of arr[l]}
```

I'm a total noob at concurrency so I was wondering if this was good practice or if there was another way of doing this?

UPDATE: Just to be clear - if "flip bits of arr[i]" and "flip bits of arr[j]" touch the same object/member for some reason, the answer "not thread safe" is obvious (and has nothing to do with arrays or the actual question), so the assumption should be that these operations do NOT touch the same memory for different i and j pairs, either directly or in some deeper level objects.

Comment: It’s hard to say if you’re not even telling us which programming language you are taking about…

Comment: If it's Java, you've got a visibility problem there

Comment: @Skorpius I recommend you explain further what you mean with "flipping the bits of the info in each index and writing back to that index"

Answer (score 5):

You don't give enough details so that one could give a definite answer so I'll make a few additional assumptions.

---

#### Thread safety

If you have:

1. Main thread: `int[] arr = new int[100]; //populate array`
2. call `t.start()` for each T1, T2, T3, T4 in the main thread, then run your loops in those threads, making sure that each thread operates on a distinct subset of indexes (which is the case in your original code due to the step of 4 in your for loop)
3. call `t.join()` for each T1, T2, T2, T4 in the main thread

then you have the following guarantees:

- at step 2, each of T1..T4 will access the same properly constructed array - this is because starting a thread creates a happens-before relationship between the array initialisation and your loops
- each thread operates on different indexes and each index can be considered as a separate `int` so they won't interfere with each other
- at this point (end of step 2), you don't have any visibility guarantee: for example the changes made by T1 are only guaranteed to be visible in T1 - in particular the main thread could still see the array in its initial state
- you therefore need to "publish" the changes through a synchronization action - one way being to join the threads in the main thread

---

#### Good practice

Here are a few general comments.

As pointed out in another answer, you should probably try to write the code in a more cache friendly way if performance is a concern.

If all each thread does is some simple bit operations on 25 ints, starting a thread will probably take more time than the operation itself and running the whole thing sequentially would be quicker. If you have a pool of threads already running (e.g. an ExecutorService) then the overhead of submitting the tasks may be small enough to provide a gain vs. sequential execution.

If you are happy to pay some performance overhead, you could also use java 8's parallel streams which allows you to write less code:

```
IntStream.range(0, arr.length).parallel()
         .forEach(i -> flip(arr[i]));
```

In any case, you should measure that what you are doing makes sense performance wise...

---

#### References:

- `Thread.start()`/`Thread.join()` create a happens before relationship: [JLS #17.4.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5)

  > - A call to `start()` on a thread happens-before any actions in the started thread.
  > - All actions in a thread happen-before any other thread successfully returns from a `join()` on that thread.
- each array element is independent: [JLS #17.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.6)

  > In particular, two threads that update adjacent elements of a byte array separately must not interfere or interact and do not need synchronization to ensure sequential consistency.

  More precisely, this is defined in [JLS #17.4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.1), which says that each array element is treated as a separate variable for the purpose of multi threading:

  > In this chapter, we use the term variable to refer to both fields and array elements.

Comment: I believe that step #2 and the second round bullet was what the essence of the question was about.

Answer (score 1):

Since the array indices are not touched by other threads this should be ok. You have a hell of a lot of false sharing going on though. A better way would be to give indices 0-24 to thread A, 25-49 to thread B, etc. That's a lot more cache friendly.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your code is merely pseudo code. (It is not Java code as tagged, so maybe you better provide us with real example code). But I'll go with the idea you have.

You have one data structure `arr`.

And you have four threads modifying `arr` concurrently.

Your code is not thread safe.

To make it thread safe you can use a mutex (one of the techniques to handle concurrency).

Wrap a mutex around the `arr`. This will *lock* `arr` and only the thread owning the mutex can access `arr`.

The mutex should be obtained in the beginning of the for loops and released in the end of the for loops.

The loops will be competing for the mutex, the order is in general unpredictable.

---

P.S.: If you can assert that no `arr` element references an object, that is referenced by another `arr` element, then you probably don't need to care too much about thread safety. But it is better to write thread safe code really.

Comment: "Your code is not thread safe" - this seems like an assertion contradicting other answers, so you should really back it up with facts (and personally, as a person who posted a bounty - but not the OP -, I'm making an assumption that none of the objects referenced by the array have mutual data - otherwise the answer "not thread safe" becomes too obvious to bother asking about in the first place)

Comment: I think your answer might be an over-simplification - note that the start indices of the loops differ by one and the step is 4, so each thread does not interact with the same member of the array as any other (i.e. they're operating on distinct subsets of the array).

Comment: @JRichardSnape I am not sure what you mean exactly. Is it maybe what I mentioned in the P.S. ?

Comment: @DVK Read the P.S. - It is mentioned there.

Comment: Yeah - I see you sort of mention it in the P.S. , but the assertion "Your code is not thread safe" is strong and up front, whereas the "Actually, you don't need to care about thread safety in this particular case" is buried in the P.S.  I think the point is - thread safety is not really a consideration in this example - unless you change it so that the threads access the same array member (obviously problematic), or you might get race conditions based on assumptions about how the main thread "sees" the contents of the array if it reads it after the threads are started.

Comment: I see what you mean, but how do you know the array elements are not distinct (The question had been edited in the meantime, but beforehand you could not know that). And thus the approach one should take is a conservative one. In general the code is not thread safe, unless you assert that all array references are distinct (which now had been added to the question).

Comment: Sure - your general point stands and I agree the question is far from clear whether it is interested in the particular case, or general comments about thread safety when accessing the same array from different threads.